# ERROR ContextLoader,localhost-startStop-1:331 - Context initialization failed

Tags: jasperserver

I'm using LDAP external authentication to log on to JasperReports Server. I've configured applicationContext-externalAuth-LDAP.xml

i.e.  in the  applicationContext-externalAuth-LDAP.xml :

```
<bean id="ldapContextSource"
       class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.ldap.JSLdapContextSource">
     <constructor-arg value="${external.ldap.url}" />
     <property name="userDn" value="${external.ldap.username}" />
     <property name="password" value="${external.ldap.password}"/>
</bean>
 the default_master.properties file contains

external.ldapUrl=ldap://hostname:389/dc=example,dc=com
external.ldapDn=cn=Administrator,dc=example,dc=com
```

Here is the stack trace of the error message:

```
  042 ERROR ContextLoader,localhost-startStop-1:331 - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'ldapContextSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-externalAuth-LDAP.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'external.ldapPassword' in string value "${external.ldapPassword}"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'external.ldapPassword' in string value "${external.ldapPassword}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:84)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:696)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:671)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5524)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1245)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1895)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'external.ldapPassword' in string value "${external.ldapPassword}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:173)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:161)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:125)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer$PlaceholderResolvingStringValueResolver.resolveStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:258)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveStringValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitPropertyValues(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitBeanDefinition(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:82)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:206)
```

Comment: This feature is available from v5.6 on. Which server version do you use? Where is the `default.properties` located?

Comment: @tobi6- I'm using Jaspersoft version - jasperreport-server-cp-6.1.0. The default.properties is located under- C:\Jaspersoft\jasperreports-server-cp-6.1.0\buildomatic

Comment: So, have you run the command `target js-ant refresh-config`? See [Buildomatic Database Password Encryption]. Just starting Jasperserver won't work.

Comment: @tobi6- I ran the command target js-ant refresh-config. Still getting the same error. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, the link I was referring to is [Buildomatic Database Password Encryption](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/buildomatic-database-password-encryption).

Answer (score 0):

When not already installed, obfuscating the password is very straightforward:

> To determine if your property is scanned by propertyConfigurer, you need to search if it is defined in one of the files in propertyConfigurer's locations. For e.g., say you are looking to encrypt the password property of *reportSchedulerMailSender* bean in *applicationContext-report-scheduling.xml*.
>
> *${report.scheduler.mail.sender.password}* tells you that *report.scheduler.mail.sender.password* is most likely defined via *propertyConfigurer* bean. Search through the propertyConfigurer locations to verify. You will be able to find this property defined in */WEB-INF/js.quartz.properties*:
>
> ```
> report.scheduler.mail.sender.password=${quartz.mail.sender.password}.
> ```

This would be a similar case to your `js.externalAuth.properties` file with its values.

> Now, *quartz.mail.sender.password* property can be encrypted in *default-master.properties* as follows:
>   Set *quartz.mail.sender.password* with a desired password in *default-master.properties*: *quartz.mail.sender.password=XXYYZZ*. If an **installation has not happened**, you can uncomment *encrypt=true* and *propsToEncrypt=dbPassword* in default-master.properties. Then, you could add *quartz.mail.sender.password* to *propsToEncrypt*:
>
> ```
> quartz.mail.sender.password=XXYYZZ
> encrypt=true
> propsToEncrypt=dbPassword,quartz.mail.sender.password
> ```
>
> After running *js-install*, verify that *report.scheduler.mail.sender.password* was encrypted in both *default-master.properties* and in */WEB-INF/js.quartz.properties*.
>
> If the installation already ran, set the properties as mentioned above and re-run it.

*BEWARE*: If you run js-install, you might wreck your JasperReport install:

> These commands will overwrite the war file created in step 1 and render the server datasources inaccessible. If you need to redeploy the war file, reset the database password(s) to plain text and start again with step 1.

[Source](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/buildomatic-database-password-encryption)